# How can i read register pymodbus with usb rs485 to modbus device?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, modbus, pymodbus

i want to read register from Modbus Device(Now modbus device is Tekon CC15) But i always got error.

This is my code:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

modbus = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB2', baudrate=9600, timeout=10)
modbus.connect()
test = modbus.read_holding_registers(0, 1, unit=1) #I want to read where register address is 0
print(test) #if i write print(test.registers) instead of this, i got this error: AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'register'
```

I always got this error:

> Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message]
> Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)

> And i also tried modbus.execute(test) then i got AttributeError:
> 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'unit_id'

And this is my logging datas

> 2020-08-08 18:58:55,570 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :238
> Transaction failed. (Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete
> message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received))  2020-08-08
> 18:58:55,570 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :235      Frame -
> [b''] not ready

Help for this or [How can i read register USB RS485 to Any Modbus Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63317485/how-can-i-read-register-usb-rs485-to-any-modbus-device/63317564?noredirect=1#comment111963147_63317564)

Comment: Can you show, or link to, information about which registers contain what values?

Comment: 0 register contain temperature value

Comment: How do you know?